# Angular 8 lazy routes resolve with and without prefix and redirect before parent

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-ivy

I am trying to work with the router and lazy loading in angular 8. I have previously successfully used it in Angular 7.
I have a few basic routes which are as follows:

```
/home
/auth
/auth/login
/auth/signUp
```

I would like `/auth` to redirect to `/auth/login` and everything else to redirect to `/home`.
To accomplish this, my `app-routing.module.ts` looks like this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

And my `auth-routing.module.ts` looks like this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/auth/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'signUp',
    component: LogoutComponent
  }
];
```

The problem is that it always redirects to the auth page and ignores the other redirects. The `/login` and `/signUp` paths are also available at a root level, which is odd, but they also work when prefixed with `/auth/login` which is even more peculiar.

So for some reason the routes seem to exist twice.
Also when I prefix the paths in `auth-routing.module.ts` with `auth/` it is suddenly possible to direct to `/auth/auth/login`

I have activated all necessary features of Angular 8  to make ivy and lazy loading work. The other routes and lazy modules I have defined are working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use relative redirects like this:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Route, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

**auth-routing.module.ts**

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Route, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

import { LogoutComponent } from './logout.component';
const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'signUp',
    component: LogoutComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule {
}
```

**home-routing.module.ts**

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Route, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {
}
```

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmsgn2 for a working example.

Comment: I have applied your suggested changes to my project, however it did not work. Since your Stackblitz works, the Problem seems to be located elsewhere. Is there anything else that could be responsible for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that You have import `AuthModule`, and `HomeModule` only in `app-routing.module.ts` (as lazy loading). Check that those modules aren't imported inside `app.module.ts` as normal (no lazy loading) way.